# Close bootstrap modal after Ajax call

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to close bootstrap-modal after Ajax call. For, this purpose I call `$(myid).modal('close')`. This event is called, but not in a proper way. Likewise, the modal box is gone but an overlay of grey color doesn't fade out some reason. Below I put my some stuff for lookup and help me.

Thanks a lot.

If I write my last two lines above `ajax_dashboard_listing()` function then hide properly

```
$('body').on('click', '.ajx', function() {    
        $id = $(this).data('target');        
        salesRepId = $(this).data('id');

        var data = {
            "target_id": $(this).data('target'),
            "target":  $('#target_'+$id).val(),
        }

        ajax_dashboard_listing(data);

        $('#exampleModalCenter_'+$id).modal('hide');
        return;        
    });
```

Comment: can you provide HTML of it so we know how exact problem is

Comment: There is nothing in html. Very common bootstrap modal html code. Main issue is modal box is not properly close after ajax call.

Comment: give me pen or fiddle of it

Answer (score 1):

`$('#modal').modal('toggle');`

Try this one. Its works for me.

Comment: Got Same result as hide. But ajax call should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Add class `close-btn` to your dismiss button modal and try this :

```
$('.close-btn').click()
```